# WebView com GTK

Tags: firefox, webview, gtk

Em Swift eu tenho uma webview que é basicamente uma janela do safári, em C#.NET eu tenho uma webview que é praticamente uma janela do IE. Mas nas demais linguagens crossplataform que usam por exemplo GTK para geração de janelas como que eu crio uma webview? tem como usar algum plugin para esta webview ser do Firefox assim como o C#.NET usa o IE? Grato desde já.

Comment: No gtk você pode usar webkitgtk, não tenho como postar uma resposta agora, mas se ninguém responder até amanhã eu posto um exemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim! Basta você utilizar o motor web do Firefox. Você precisa entender que o motor web seria como um interpretador. Quando digitamos um endereço num determinado navegador, ele primeiramente converte o DNS (domínio da página) para o IP do site ("endereço" original dele na rede) e a partir do que descobriu-se, ele faz uma conexão com o servidor e o servidor retorna a nós (o cliente) códigos. E a tarefa do motor é interpretar esses códigos.

Nunca utilizei o motor web do Firefox, mas já ouvi falar no Webkit, que por sinal já é muito documentado e trabalha bem com o GTK+.